# R : How to write confusion matrix with decision tree output?

Tags: python, r, decision-tree, confusion-matrix

I am studying decision tree and confusion matrix.
I am not doing coding in R script, but I would like to know how can I make confusion matrix from the attached screenshot, which is the output of rpart in R script.

I tried to get TP, FP, TN and TN but can not get ...
can you help me to understand?
The target value is either 0 or 1.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agayW.png)

Comment: As it's currently written, we will not be able to answer your question, because it lacks a lot of important information: What procedure did you already use (provide script or exact functions)? What data / object do you have in R (provide data or snippet)? And what kind of output/result do you expect (provide fictional or real example)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You have a classification problem and You know ground truth labels for Your data - You need to combine the ground truth labels with the output from the model for each data point. Next, You'll need to count how many of Your observations were classified correctly by the tree and how many of them were classified incorrectly. These counts are TP, TN, FP and FN.

In R, there's a library `caret` which provides `confusionMatrix()` function. Please, take a look at documentation for the details and example usage. In particular, You need to specify which class (0 or 1 in Your case) is the event You'd like to record.

Your question is unclear so my answer is general.